# Получаю ошибку при попытке приведения типов

Tags: c++, qt, типы-данных, преобразование-типов

Написал вот такой код:

```
static int cmp(const void* a, const void* b) {

   return(  ((massifVoltageAndIndex*)a)->Voltage - 
   ((massifVoltageAndIndex*)b)->Voltage  );

}
```

При сборки получил предупреждение "old-style cast" попытался исправить на

```
static int cmp(const void* a, const void* b) {

   return(  (reinterpret_cast<massifVoltageAndIndex*>(a))->Voltage - 
   (reinterpret_cast<massifVoltageAndIndex*>(b))->Voltage  );

}
```

Но получил ошибку:

```
 error: reinterpret_cast from type ‘const void*’ to type 
 ‘massifVoltageAndIndex*’ casts away qualifiers
 return(  (reinterpret_cast<massifVoltageAndIndex*>(a))->Voltage - 
 (reinterpret_cast<massifVoltageAndIndex*>(b))->Voltage  );
                                                    ^
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Кушаем слона по кусочку :)

```
static int cmp(const void* a, const void* b) 
{
    return ((reinterpret_cast<massifVoltageAndIndex*>(const_cast<void*>(a)))->Voltage -
            (reinterpret_cast<massifVoltageAndIndex*>(const_cast<void*>(b)))->Voltage);
}
```

Comment: Это какая-то перверсия...

Answer (score 1):

Здесь нет ни одной причины использовать C-style, reinterpret или const кастование:

```
static int cmp(const void* a, const void* b)
{
   using Ptr = massifVoltageAndIndex const *;
   return static_cast<Ptr>(a)->Voltage - static_cast<Ptr>(b)->Voltage;
}
```

Comment: А теперь уберите `const` и повторите - изначально ведь вопрос ТС ставился привести к *неконстантному* указателю. Может, там еще с десяток строк перед этим... :)

Comment: @Harry Нет, привести именно к неконстантному указателю вопрос не ставился. В приведенном примере с функцией сравнения это совершенно ни к чему. А даже в маловероятном сценарии, когда `Voltage` являлись бы экземплярами некоторого хитрого класса с перегруженным оператором -, модифицирующим этот экземпляры, и соответственно требующим ссылок на неконстантные объектов, необходимость к приведению к указателю на неконстантный объект просто означала бы что ОП делает что-то не так.